# Determine if authorized org with SalesforceDX is Developer or Production

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, developer-productivity, auth

I'm struggling to determine the type of environment of authorized orgs using the SalesforceDX auth commands.

Once you've registered an org if you run

`sfdx force:org:list --json`

The output results in the following information

```
{
    "orgId": "00D9XXXXXXXXX",
    "accessToken": "XXXXXX",
    "instanceUrl": "https://XXX.my.salesforce.com",
    "loginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "username": "xxx@xxx.com",
    "clientId": "PlatformCLI",
    "connectedStatus": "Connected",
    "lastUsed": "2020-03-10T14:37:24.471Z"
}
```

With that, I'm unable to determine if the org is a Developer Org or a real Production Org (since the loginUrl is the same for both).

Any ideas on how to determine it without need to login or query the org directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also can just query for sandbox (which includes Scratch Orgs):

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT IsSandbox FROM Organization LIMIT 1" -u [your_alias]
```

This will return true. 
When using this in a build script always use `--json` and process the result - I prefer [.jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse the JSON

To differentiate the edition use

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT OrganizationType FROM Organization LIMIT 1" -u [your_alias]
```

which returns "Developer Edition" versus your real production edition like "Enterprise Edition"

Comment: Thank you Christian, I imagine that there's no way to obtain it directly from the `org` topic then, we're forced to query the org.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is relevant with the assumption that your Orgs have a custom domain setup (based on the information as it seems in the question). If not, you will still need an additional step to find that information.

---

For any **Developer Edition Orgs**, the subdomain always ends with **-dev-ed**.

As an example:

`"instanceUrl": "https://mydomainname-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com"`

This is also mentioned in this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/identity_login/identity_login_my_domain):

> The subdomain ends with -dev-ed, which means that the subdomain is a Salesforce Developer Edition

Comment: But only if they've set up a custom domain... otherwise it's just a plain "naXX" or something. At that point, you need to query Organization or look at Company Information in Setup.

Comment: That's a good point. I just went ahead assuming this based on the question that the domain is already setup.

Answer (score -1):

The instanceUrl from

```
sfdx force:org:list --json
```

would also refer the org if the domain is set

During Login we can set the org name Example:

**Developer Org**

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a myHubOrg
```

**Production Org**

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a myProdOrg
```

The current configuration of the instance can be checked by

```
sfdx force:config:list
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_config.htm